# How to replace whole SQL table data frequently?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

I have a Spring application that runs a cron on it. The cron every few minutes gets new data from external API. The data should be stored in a database (MySQL), in place of old data (Old data should be overwritten by new data). **The data requires to be overwritten instead of updated**. The application itself provides REST API so the client is able to get the data from the database. So there should not be situation that client sees an empty or just a part of data from database because there is an data update.
Currently I've tried deleting whole old data and insert new data but there is a place that a client gets just a part of the data. I've tried it via Spring Data deleteAll and saveAll methods.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Country> overrideAll(@NonNull Iterable<Country> countries) {
    removeAllAndFlush();

    List<CountryEntity> countriesToCreate = stream(countries.spliterator(), false)
            .map(CountryEntity::from)
            .collect(toList());

    List<CountryEntity> createdCountries = repository.saveAll(countriesToCreate);

    return createdCountries.stream()
            .map(CountryEntity::toCountry)
            .collect(toList());
}

private void removeAllAndFlush() {
    repository.deleteAll();
    repository.flush();
}
```

I also thought about having a temporary table that gets new data and when the data is complete just replace main table with temporary table. Is it a good idea? Any other ideas?

Comment: Or switch alternatingly between two twin tables maybe using an SQL view.

Comment: Yeah, you can load data into another table. Then rename old table to something else & rename new table as the table being used.

Comment: *The data requires to be overwritten instead of updated.* [REPLACE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) do this. And I'd recommend you to save new data into temporary table then replace data via one query - this is fast enough and avoids *situation that client sees an empty or just a part of data*.

Comment: *The data should be stored in a database (MySQL), in place of old data (Old data should be overwritten by new data).* The whole old data must be removed and new data stored instead? or only the rows from old data which matches new data by some criteria (some GUID, for example) must be overwritten?

Comment: Whole old data must be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea. You can minimize the downtime by working on another table until it's ready and then switch tables quickly by renaming. This will also improve perceived performance by the users because no record needs to be locked like what happens when using UPDATE/DELETE.

In MySQL, you can use RENAME TABLE if you don't have triggers on the table. It allows multiple table renaming at once and it works atomically (i.e. transaction - if any error happens, no change is made). You can use the following for example

```
RENAME TABLE countries TO countries_old, countries_new TO countries;
DROP TABLE countries_old;
```

Refer here for more details

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html